# flask_bcrypt password mismatch error in custom login

Tags: python, bcrypt

Jambo,

i have been trying to implement a custom login with flask_bycrypt but i've noticed an inconsistency in the produced passwords .

creating the user password_hash and testing with hash from user input:

```
....
# passwd = some user input
# storing the password
self.password_hash =  bcrypt.hashpw(passwd.encode(), bcrypt.gensalt(14))



    # user = some user object from the db
    # passwd = some user input

    password = bcrypt.hashpw(passwd.encode(), bcrypt.gensalt(14))
    hashed = user.password_hash

    if hashed == password:
       return login_user(user)
    else:
       return 'passwords did not match'
```

passwords don't match.

Answer (score 2):

Generated hash is different every time, you need to use `bcrypt.checkpw` method to verify whether the password is correct. It is shown at https://github.com/pyca/bcrypt/#password-hashing. So, the code in your example should look like this:

```
    hashed = user.password_hash
    if bcrypt.checkpw(passw.encode(), hashed):
       return login_user(user)
    else:
       return 'passwords did not match'
```